# Why is there a key error?

Tags: python

I am making a list of enemys with their damages for a text based game and I get a keyError

```
import random

monsters = {"Goblin":1, "Troll":3, "Bear":2, "Giant Spider": 1, "Bandit":1,"Wolf":1,"Homeless Man":1, "Goblin Chief":3}
monsterNum = 0

for monster in monsters:
    monsterNum += 1

def spawnMonster():
    global output
    num = random.randint(0, monsterNum)
    print(num)
    global enemy
    enemy = monsters[num]
    print(enemy)
    output = "A " + monster + " comes out of the bushes."

spawnMonster()
print(output)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in spawnMonster
KeyError: 7
```

Comment: Where is the keyerror? Post the traceback

Comment: get rid of that `for` loop, and all those `global` declarations. They are unnecessary

Comment: You have the logic backwards, the values are ints and the keys are the monster names

Comment: Use `len()` to check the dictionary's size. You don't have to calculate it manually.

Comment: A final note that has not been noted! Both the arguments to `randint` are ***inclusive*** ... So if the random value comes out as `8` ... You're gone for a toss!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I think the values are supposed to mean the monster's level, or something else like that. Notice that `1` appears multiple times—I don't think that's because all of those are somehow supposed to be "monster #1". (Although if I'm wrong, he's got an even more fundamental design problem, obviously…)

Comment: @abarnert, yep,  I just meant the OP was accessing using the wrong thing, I think he/she was getting a little mixed up between how a list and a dict works and actually are based on *I am making a list of enemys with their damages*.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Yeah, I think you're right about that.

Answer (score 3):

Your dictionary, `monsters`, is keyed by monster name, not be number.

But you're passing a number, `num`, as a key.

One way to solve this would be to use a `list` of (name, level) tuples (I'm just guessing that the values in your dict are levels…), rather than a `dict`.

But an even better solution is to use `random.choice` instead of `random.randint`:

```
def spawnMonster():
    global output
    enemy = random.choice(list(monsters))
    print(enemy)
    output = "A " + monster + " comes out of the bushes."
```

Or, of course, combine the two:

```
monsters = [("Goblin", 1), ("Troll", 3), ("Bear", 2), ("Giant Spider", 1), ("Bandit", 1), ("Wolf", 1), ("Homeless Man", 1), ("Goblin Chief", 3)]
```

## ...

```
enemy, level = random.choice(monsters)
```

---

While we're at it, you've got a couple other errors in your code:

- You're putting the monster name in a variable named `enemy`, but then you try to use a variable named `monster`.
- `randint(0, monsterNum)` gives you a number from 0 to `monsterNum` *including `monsterNum`*. But that will be 1 too many, and, even if you had a list, you'd get an `IndexError` every time it picks the last number. Use `randrange`, not `randint`, for indexes.
- While `monsterNum = 0` then `for monster in monsters: monsterNum += 1` does work, it's a lot simpler to just do `monsterNum = len(monsters)`.
- While using `global output` works as a way to pass information back from the function, a much better way is to just `return output`, and have the outer code do `print(spawnMonster())`.

Answer (score 2):

Because this line:

> ```
> monsters[num]
> ```

attempts to use a key that doesn't exist in the dictionary. Python dictionaries are not PHP associative arrays; values within the dictionary are *only* accessible via their associated key.

Create a list of monsters instead and use `random.choice()` to choose one from there.